# Tools to demonstrate load balancing and scheduling in the cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, nginx, cloud, load-balancing

I have been asked by my professor at university to demonstrate how load balancing happens on the cloud. Like, for example, what kind of tools are used to do it.

I have looked at some like nginx, Pen etc, but running them on my laptop to demonstrate load balancing is a little far fetched. I have also looked at the Google App Engine, which seems feasible, but it load balances automatically.

Is there another way I can demonstrate this?

**EDIT:** I'm looking at Open-Source software only, I can't pay a fee to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you considered amazon ?

also

http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/loadbalancers/

Does this help?

http://askville.amazon.com/open-source-load-balancer-software-run-Linux/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=7650176

Answer (score 1):

Some pointers to think about:

TCP mode vs HTTP mode (some tools support both) - you will want to know what difference is.

Load balancing versus load distribution.

Load balancing strategies (eg hashing/consistent hashing, cookies, round robin and more).

Good luck !